# Bottle with multiple apps

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle, multiple-projects

How do I manage multiple apps in Bottle, served from the one `run`?

#### App 0

```
from bottle import Bottle

app0 = Bottle()

@app0.route('/app0/')
def app0_route():
    return {'`app0` says': 'Greetings!'}
```

#### App 1

```
from bottle import Bottle

app1 = Bottle()

@app1.route('/app1/')
def app1_route():
    return {'`app1` says': 'Greetings!'}
```

#### Main

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app0.run()    # How do I link `app1` here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can merge all routes in `app1` using `Bottle.merge`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app0.merge(app1)
    app0.run()
```

It does not change the original owner, see [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.merge).